# Unable to load springConfigurations in stepDefs using spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Application configuration are not recognized in Testing.
Dependencies from build.gradle

```
springBootVersion = '1.3.3.RELEASE'

testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test',
    "info.cukes:cucumber-jvm:1.2.4",
    "info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.2.4",
    "info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4",
    "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4",
    "info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.2.4",
    'commons-io:commons-io:2.4')
```

CukeOptions

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
                  format = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber" },
                  features = "src/test/resources/features",
                  dryRun = false
                )
public class CukeOptions{
}
```

cucumberMain.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@ContextConfiguration(classes = IngestBatchApplication.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class CucumberMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
     JUnitCore jUnitCore = new JUnitCore();
        jUnitCore.run(CukeOptions.class);
    }

}
```

Here is my stepDefs

```
public class stepDefs {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @When("^And get user details$")
    public void get_user_details() throws Throwable {
      // Unable to get user details from bean
    }
}
```

ApplicationContext returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@ContextConfiguration(classes = IngestBatchApplication.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class stepDefs {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @When("^And get user details$")
    public void get_user_details() throws Throwable {
      // Unable to get user details from bean
    }
}
```